# Sort columns values based on floats inside a string, then concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a pretty messy DF. Looking like this, but with 30 columns:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| some text (other text) : 56.3% (text again: 40%) | again text (not same text) : 33% (text text: 60.1%) |
| text (always text) : 26.6% (aaand text: 80%) | still text (too much text) : 86% (last text: 10%) |

What I'm trying to do is creating another column, c, which concat a & b, but the concatenation must be sorted based on the first number (I don't whant to change row's order). Result expected:

| c |
| --- |
| some text (other text) : 56% (text again: 40%) again text (not same text) : 33% (text text: 60%) |
| still text (too much text) : 86% (last text: 10%) text (always text) : 26% (aaand text: 80%) |

Any idea ?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: What code have you tried and is it ascending or descending?

Comment: it is ambiguous whether you want to use the first or second or both percentages

Comment: the first percentages is the one for sorting. I've tried and deleted a lot of code, spliting inside another temporary df, sorting, concatenate, but it was too messy and doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `apply` a customized function

```py
def concat(row):
    keys = row.str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)%')[0].astype(float).tolist()
    row = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(keys, row.tolist()))]
    return ' '.join(row)

df['c'] = df.apply(concat, axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

                                                  a                                                  b
0  some text (other text) : 56.3% (text again: 40%)  again text (not same text) : 33% (text text: 6...
1      text (always text) : 26.6% (aaand text: 80%)  still text (too much text) : 86% (last text: 10%)
                                                  a  \
0  some text (other text) : 56.3% (text again: 40%)
1      text (always text) : 26.6% (aaand text: 80%)

                                                     b  \
0  again text (not same text) : 33% (text text: 60.1%)
1    still text (too much text) : 86% (last text: 10%)

                                                                                                      c
0  again text (not same text) : 33% (text text: 60.1%) some text (other text) : 56.3% (text again: 40%)
1        text (always text) : 26.6% (aaand text: 80%) still text (too much text) : 86% (last text: 10%)
```

Comment: When god arrives.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have this error message:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
And after looking at my data, it's not int, but floats, sorry...

I updated the post

Comment: Thanks a lot it is perfect and cristal clear !